# How to properly import jquery validation via npm

Tags: javascript, jquery, npm, jquery-validate, node-modules

How do I properly import `jquery validation` via `npm` ?

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-validation). I tried to simply put:
`@import jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js` to my `scripts` but

I got some errors in my next scripts so I just downloaded the code and imported in this way:

`<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-validation.js') }}"></script>`

I would, although, prefer the `import` from `node_modules` but I did not find any guide to do it properly.

Comment: did you do `npm install jquery-validation`?
You might want to go through this: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally

Comment: yes, I did but I need to import it now :)

Comment: How about `const  jquery-validation= require('jquery-validation');` at the top of your app.js? What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: Ouh, id does work, thanks! I thought that it does not matter if I use the `import` or `require`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put

```
const jquery-validation = require('jquery-validation');
```

at the top of your app.js

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but importing it worked for me :

```js
import jqueryValidate from "jquery-validation";
```

(don't forget to `npm i jquery-validation` first of course)